# Doubt in Raoultian and Henrian Standard State

Tags: condensed-matter, thermodynamics, statistical-thermodynamics, materials-engineering

$Si(liq)=Si_\text{(1 wt% Fe)}$

Can you describe what is going on here?All that they ask for is change in Gibbs free energy for the process.I am completely unable to figure why this particular model is so important for a specific question.It would be great if someone could interpret both the analytical and the mathematical analogy to this.There is also a difference between Raoultian and Henrian State which is to be applied here. I do not understand which one I am supposed to use when.Why is $\text{1 wt% Fe}$ so important?

Comment: I don't have time to write a good answer, but maybe this will help.  You can either write your own answer if it does or if it does not someone else might be able to.  This should be the gibbs free energy of mixing.  http://web.mst.edu/~billf/chap7.pdf

Comment: @user586228 did Tristan's comment help? Let us know please! I didn't play any role in this question's closure, but I can tell you that it doesn't need to be closed "permanently", as long as the question maintains some level of engagement.